# Cards come with margin-right

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to display three cards in a grid. The media of the card has a max-width of 345px but because of that the card gets a lot of margin-right. Styling doesn't look good in a grid. Anyone know how I can get rid of the margin?

I have an example made in sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/6451nx4ypr

[image]

Comment: There is no margin-right, the card `.ImgMediaCard-card-1 ` take the maximum allowed space `max-width: 345px;` and the card items each have 33% width in space. What should happen? do you want to center them?

Comment: Yes, just spread them out nice in the grid with even with space. Because the right side now has more white space. @kunukn

Comment: You could add following css: `.ImgMediaCard-card-1{ margin: 0 auto; }`

Comment: It is  a bit unclear what are you trying to achieve? Grid divides the screen to four, if you limit the size of the card, what do you expect to happen with the extra space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the grid. The Card has max size, but the grid is larger. This leave some extra space. If you look in the debugger, there is no margin to change.

You can try the following:

```
const styles = {
  card: {
    maxWidth: 345
  },
  gridFour: {
    maxWidth: 345
  },
  media: {
    // ⚠️ object-fit is not supported by IE11.
    objectFit: "cover",
  }
};
```

And in the change the grid class to:

```
<Grid item sm={4} className={classes.gridFour}>
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/embed/k3k2m35mz5

You can also center the cards in the `Grid`:

```
const styles = {
  card: {
    maxWidth: 345,
    margin: 'auto'
  },
  gridFour: {
    align: 'center'
  },
  media: {
    // ⚠️ object-fit is not supported by IE11.
    objectFit: "cover"
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it works differently in React, but in Angular, I just apply classes to whatever it is I need to restyle and it seems to take.

If you have the objects in another container of some kind, make sure it doesn't apply some margin/space (like a flex container or something). Apply something to the container items to strip away any of that.

Simple example, this strips away all padding and margins and has the predictable effect on the backgrounds (I just tried it in a project, it works as expected):

```
mat-card {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: grey;
}

mat-card-content {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with bootstrap, there is this feature called grid offsets. Unfortunately, this is still not a feature to material-ui.

So, what you can do is remove the max-width on your cards. Then add an empty Grid to the sides to create an offset.

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting the width to be defined and should fluid on the screen when the screen width increased is as showed in [this codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/ww5o80q07l) link.
And this will have default width as 4 and doesn't have custom style to define a width to considered as responsive width.

Comment: @PeterRosevelt, do you have time to check the mentioned codepen link?